# Ubuntu does not wake up after suspension or hibernation

Tags: grub2, 18.04, suspend, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. After I close the lid (for 1 min+), Ubuntu refuses to wake up. It flashes an error screen instead: [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnNZu.jpg)

I have no clue why this happens so unfortunately cannot provide more details here.

I usually work around the issue by rebooting.But it takes a long time since I am using a HDD.

Comment: The screenshot is not an error - its the system log when it is trying to start up and apparently it failed to start the graphics screen. It'll be easier to debug the problem with a system log - please try this: after you reproduce the problem, and reboot and have a running system, run in a terminal: `journalctl -b-1 | tail -n500 | curl -F 'clbin=<-' https://clbin.com` and post here the URL that it gives you. This will send the last 500 system log lines from your previous boot to a pastebin site.